# Angular + Require + Angular-resources and cookies modules lead to "Error: No module: ngResource"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am not able to use `ngResource` using `require.js` I am having exactly same problem as discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/I6CSeG0Z2Vo)

Below is my code :

```
main.js ( data-main attribute of require.js ) 

// https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/I6CSeG0Z2Vo
require.config({
    paths: {
        'angular': '../bower_components/angular/angular',
        'angularResource': '../node_modules/angular-resource/angular-resource'
    },
    shim:{
        'angular':{
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularResource':{
            deps: ['angular'],
            exports: 'angularResource'
        }
    }
});
debugger;
require(['controllers/MainCtrl']);
require(['directives/owNavigation']);
require(['directives/owFooter']);
```

Below is my app.js where I am creating my angular app module.

```
app.js

define(['angular','angularResource'],function(angular,angularResource){
    debugger;
    var app = angular.module('app',['ngResource']);
    return {
        angularModule: app
    }
});
```

But, '`angularResouce`' parameter is always `null`.   I can see '`angular`' parameter has proper value and I can create my 'app' module without passing '`ngResource`' as a dependency.

I am using below version

- Angularjs v1.6.6
- RequireJS 2.3.5
- angular-resource v1.6.6

I can see in chrome developer tool's network tab that `requirejs` is loading file '`angular-resource.js`' but still `app.js` module is not receiving it as a parameter.

[image]

Here is the error that can be seen on console

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete export from the shim angularResource :

```
shim:{
        'angular':{
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        'angularResource':{
            deps: ['angular']
        }
    }
```

It should work (working for me), keeping everything else same.